# Add a comma after the final author in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, natbib

How can I add a comma after the final author in my bibliography? (basically all components need to be separated with a comma)
I am using the following:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-acs, articletitle=false, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{first-last}                          %puts firstname first
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}       %changes numbers in reference list to square brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1},}              %italic journal title with comma
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want "W. Lu, et al. Inorg. Chem." or "W. Lu et al., Inorg. Chem."?

Comment: @moewe I want the following: W. Lu et al., Inorg. Chem., 2017, 56, 8223.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 2):

`chem-acs` implements a specific journal style and is not meant to be fully customisable. As such many separators are hard-coded in the style. While they can simply be changed, the required code to modify all separators to commas would easily amass hundreds of lines of code in the preamble. So it would probably be easiest to just take `chem-acs.bbx`, rename it and change the punctuation in each `\setunit` instance to `\addcomma\space`.

So here is a *very dangerous* workaround. We tell `\setunit` to ignore its argument and always print `\addcomma\space` regardless of what the style actually says. This works as long as you really want *all* punctuations to be commas, but breaks down if there are places where you want something else.

In the following MWE it works rather well, but this is not guaranteed in general.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-acs, articletitle=false, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{given-family}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \long\def\blx@setunit#1{%
    \iftoggle{blx@keepunit}
      {}
      {\long\gdef\blx@unitpunct{\addcomma\space}%
       \global\toggletrue{blx@unit}}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: E. Sigfridsson, U. Ryde, Journal of Computational Chemistry, 1998, 19, 377–395.]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is exactly what I wanted. It took literally few weeks to try to figure out how to add those stupid comma's haha